# Experience editor "view" tab is missing

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor

I am experiencing an issue with `Sitecore 9.2`. When I open Experience Editor: *sitelocation*/?sc_mode=edit Ribbon tab "VIEW" is missing and I am not able to navigate to another page using the navigation bar. I checked the configuration `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config` and it has not changed. There is no error in logs in the log file or in a browser console.

Any ideas that could help, or any places where I can look for some kind of configuration or in Core DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick checks that you can try are as below:

1. Clean up the Core database and do an IIS reset.
2. If that does not work, go to your Core DB to see if you have the buttons in there, screenshot below for reference:
   [image: CoreDBViewTab]

3. Check if the "View" tab has read access. For a tab to appear, the user must have read access to the tab definition item and at least one group on that tab.

4. Since you mentioned that you already verified the configs though, but it would be good if you could cross-check the configs with a fresh Sitecore instance of the same version.

Comment: The problem was solved in combination of steps 1 and 2. 

I noticed that items from screenshot were missing in my environment so I installed them from clean Sitecore 9.2 instance using package manager. After that I cleaned up Core DB and did IIS reset. It works perfect now. Thank you.

Comment: Great! glad to know you got it fixed :-)